# How to draw a sequence of points as a line in OpenCV3?

Tags: drawing, line, opencv3.0

I like to draw a sequence of points as a line on OpenCV 3.3. I think I can collect this sequence by `vector<Point>` although I don't know is this the best idea or not.
Lets consider I have these points vector:

```
 vector<Point> vec = { Point(0,0),Point(10,10),Point(20,20), Point(30,30), Point(40,40), Point(50,50) };
```

And I like to draw them in an empty `Mat` as an 100*100 pixel image. So it would be the images diameter. I searched and found the `line` function, but it has only to "starting and end" points. Should I use many line functions in sequence? There isn't better solution for this?

I tried to do it by writing this code but it thrown in an exception:

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

void MyLine(Mat img, Point start, Point end);
Mat im = Mat::zeros(100, 100, CV_8UC1);
Mat img = Mat::zeros(100, 100, CV_8UC1);
vector<Point> vec = { Point(0,0),Point(10,10),Point(20,20), Point(30,30), Point(40,40), Point(50,50) };

int main()
{
    Point start= Point(0, 0);
    Point end = Point(50, 50);

    MyLine(img, start, end);
    namedWindow("image", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    imshow("image", im);
    waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}

void MyLine(Mat img, Point start, Point end)
{
    int thickness = 2;
    int lineType = 8;
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
    {
        line(img,
            vec[i],
            vec[i+1],
            Scalar(255, 255, 255),
            thickness,
            lineType);
        im += img;    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `drawContours(...)` function like this:

```
vector<vector<Point>> contours = {vec};
drawContours(im, contours, -1, Scalar(255, 255, 255), thickness, lineType);
```

Comment: I usually do the shorter: `drawContours(im, vector<vector<Point>>{vec}, 0, Scalar(255, 255, 255), thickness, lineType);`

Comment: Thank you guys!
I have one question, why we should use vector of vector of points for drawing contours? why we can not use vector of points instead?

I mean:  drawContours(im, vec, -1, Scalar(255, 255, 255), thickness, lineType);

Comment: Because function called as drawContours, not drawContour. It accept set of contours, not single contour.